# Storing a type and programmatically casting another variable to the stored type

Tags: c++

I'd like to do something along the lines of:

```
Type type = int; // or type_of(some_other_variable)
double variable = 42.0;
std::cout << (type)variable;
```

Is it possible?

EDIT: What I'm really trying to do is make a Qt-style Variant and VariantMap. My current code is;

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct Variant
{
    bool m_bool;
    int m_int;
    double m_double;
    std::string m_string;

    Variant() {};
    Variant(bool bBoolean) { m_bool = bBoolean; }
    Variant(int iInteger) { m_int = iInteger; }
    Variant(double dDouble) { m_double = dDouble; }
    Variant(std::string sString) { m_string = sString; }
    Variant(const char *_Ptr) { m_string = _Ptr; }

    operator bool() { return m_bool; }
    operator int() { return m_int; }
    operator double() { return m_double; }
    operator std::string() { return m_string; }
};

typedef std::map<std::string, Variant> VariantMap;

int main()
{
    VariantMap map;
    map["bool"] = true;
    map["int"] = 42;
    map["double"] = 3.14159265358979323846;
    map["string"] = "foobar";

    std::cout
        << "bool " << static_cast<bool>(map["bool"]) << std::endl
        << "int" << static_cast<int>(map["int"]) << std::endl
        << "double " << static_cast<double>(map["double"]) << std::endl
        << "string "<< static_cast<std::string>(map["string"]) << std::endl
        ;

    system("pause");



 return 1;
}
```

But instead of explicitly casting to the contained type when access is needed, I'd like to store the type at assignment, and and auto-cast to the stored type at access.

Comment: You really need to tell us what problem you're trying to solve. Just telling us how you would like to solve it doesn't give us enough information. For example, it's possible `#define type int` will solve your problem. But it's also possible that has nothing to do with your problem. We can't tell because we don't know what your problem actually is.

Comment: i've done such. the top post is now edited to include an explanation of my application.

Comment: Weird the you accepted an answer that doesn't answer your actual question. There is an answer, use a discriminated union with an `operator<<` overload.

Comment: thank you! could you provide a code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using type = int; // or: typedef int type;
std::cout << static_cast<type>(variable); // prefer static_cast to C-style cast
```

Now, if you mean that `type` will not be known until runtime (because it depends on user input, or something) then what you are asking is not possible in C++.

Comment: pretty slick. how would it be possible to store the type as a class member though?

Comment: @rogueyoshi put the `using` or `typedef` declaration inside the class definition

Comment: ah, but it can't be redefined unfortunately. is there a solution to that?

Comment: @rogueyoshi You can redefine it in a derived class, or in a nested scope. Is that good enough? If not, please provide more detail on what you are trying to do.

Comment: i've just edited in the top post for what i'm trying to do.

Comment: also, yes i guess what i want is what you say, runtime storage of type, isn't possible. this is a pretty good solution for other applications though, so i'll mark it as the answer.